# Find the number of function/macro calls under a compile time macro

Tags: c, function, macros

I have this problem that i have to find how many times a specific macro/function is being called in my code? I know you might think why dont i run a find/grep. But my problem is that the function/macro being called is under a specific compile time macro. So i would like to find the number of calls only when this specific compile time macro is enabled. And i want to find number of calls in the whole code (static analysis, not runtime). The codebase is quite huge (millions of lines of code) and fully in C on linux. I was trying to use readelf but i could not really extract the needed info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
~N

Answer (score 2):

Many C compiliers have a flag to output the pre-processor stage intermediate output (with the relevant conditional compile symbols defined). You could then run find/grep on this output.

Answer (score 0):

How about embedding some unique word(like `MARKER` in the following)
in the said macro, and counting the number of times that the word appears?
For example, assuming a code `a.c` like the following:

```
#define A f() MARKER
#define B A; A;
B
```

The count that the marker appears will be obtained with the commands like
the following:

```
gcc -E a.c | sed -r 's/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/\xa/g' | grep MARKER | wc -l
```

After the measurement, `MARKER` in the macro will need to be removed
or `#define`d to empty as:

```
#define MARKER
```

**EDIT:**
If your build system is `make`, you may need to add a new rule like the
following to your current makefiles so as to make preprocessed file:

```
SRCS = a.c

preprocessed: $(SRCS:.c=.i)

%.i: %.c
    $(CC) -E $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

If all the settings have been done properly,
by the use of `make preprocessed` and `find -type f -name '*.i'` or similar
command, all the preprocessed files will be obtained.
Probably this isn't an easy job.
If you have fallen into difficulties,
I'd suggest posting that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ise, i too had thought of this approach but was unable to use it as i could not run "gcc -E test.c -o test.i" on the files.. When i do so it throws some catastrophic error saying it could not find some include files etc.. My project has quite many directories and include files are spread over in number of places.. So I am not quite sure if there is any options i need to include to run.. Sorry i know i am asking a quite trivial question..